# Saving tweets using tweepy in json format

Tags: python, json, rest, tweepy, information-retrieval

How can we collect tweets using tweepy in json format and save to local disk. I need to input the json file in Solr for indexing and tokenization. here is the code i am using:

`

```
 import json
 import tweepy
 from tweepy import OAuthHandler

 ckey=""
 csecret=""
 atoken=""
 asecret=""

 auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
 auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

 api = tweepy.API(auth)

 data1 = api.search(q='politics', count = 1)`
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific as for what is the error you see? Or what is the output you get and what you expect?

Comment: @toti08 ..... i am getting the following response when i print data1:
{"created_at":"Sat Sep 08 17:44:57 +0000 2018","id":1038483340926509057,"id_str":"1038483340926509057","text":"RT : Either Kerala Floods have seriously damaged the...}

                        i believe this is a json format only. What i need is what code do i need to add in python so that this output is stored in json file on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try saving your data as a `list` and dump it into a `json` file, given that you already imported `json`.

```
z = [x for x in data1]

with open('your_data.json', 'w') as out:
    json.dump(z,out)
```

alternatively, you could write `z = [x for x in data1]` as:

```
z = list()
for x in data1:
    z.append(x)
```

/ogs